# Переход между JFrame и ОБРАТНО

Tags: java

У меня есть две формы, как переходить из одной в другую я понял:

```
building.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Building build = new Building();
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

Но как из новой формы, которая вылетает, попасть обратно, в предыдущую, не теряя никаких данных и вычислений?

Comment: Если нужно запросить у пользователя данные в отдельной форме, а основное окно сделать недоступным, то может быть проще воспользоваться модальным диалогом?

Comment: Нет) ничего запрашивать не надо. 
В одном фрейме(А) у меня находятся кнопка для перехода в другой фрейм(Б).
в Б у меня стоят счетчики и таймер.
Мне нужно, чтобы я заходил в Б, включал все эти таймеры, и возвращался в фрейм А, но при этом, чтобы вычисления в Б продолжали работать.

Comment: Я в переходе из А в Б использовал setVisible, до этого стоял dispose();
но как я понял dispose() сбрасывает данные вроде.

Comment: Кто нибудь поможет вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо, чтобы что-то работало в фоне, то самый простой вариант это [поток](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) или если относительно Java это  [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). Т.к. вы используете UI и судя по всему это Swing, полезно будет узнать какие потоки есть в этом фреймворке и как они взаимодействуют, читать [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)(поможет при решении проблем замирания, особенно с учетом того, что вы хотите что-то в фоне вычислять).

Comment: Великолепно!!
просто великолепно, я уже и забыл об этом вопросе))
Спасибо тебе)) 
В моем обучении java всегда попадаются забористые вопросы, как с созданием нескольких объектов :) 
Где можно тебя найти? Мне хотелось бы, чтобы ты стал моим ментором на некоторое время)

Comment: @OgneFF Эм, это конечно очень лестно. Но не уверен, что у меня есть достаточно времени, чтобы заниматься менторством. Так что вы можете оставлять свои вопросы на этом сайте, кто-то вам обязательно поможет =)